# Erro no Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Como posso corrigir esse erro? Não achei nada a respeito na internet... esse é o script

`using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class BlueCubeBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{

```
private Rigidbody BlueCubeMovement;

private NavMeshAgent FollowPlayer;

public Transform PlayerPosition;

private Renderer Appearance;

private bool ActiveNavMesh;

float Velocity = Random.Range(2.5f, 5.8f);

void Start()
{

    ActiveNavMesh = false;

    tag = "YellowEnemyCube";

    float ScaleOfCube = Random.Range(1.0f, 3.8f);

    BlueCubeMovement = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    Appearance = GetComponent<Renderer>();

    FollowPlayer = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();

    Appearance.material.color = Color.blue;

    transform.localScale = new Vector3(ScaleOfCube, ScaleOfCube, ScaleOfCube);

    BlueCubeMovement.mass = Random.Range(1.0f, 15.0f);

}

void Update()
{

    if (ActiveNavMesh == true) {

        FollowPlayer.destination = PlayerPosition.position;

        FollowPlayer.velocity = new Vector3(Velocity, Velocity, Velocity);

    }

}

private void OnCollisionEnter()
{
    if (BlueCubeMovement.angularVelocity == new Vector3(0, 0, 0)) {

        ActiveNavMesh = true;

    }

}

private void OnCollisionStay()
{
    if (BlueCubeMovement.angularVelocity == new Vector3(0, 0, 0)) {

        ActiveNavMesh = true;

    }

}
```

}` esse script está em um cubo... e aprece o seguinte erro [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

Essa linha está causando erro no seu código pois você está iniciando um objeto fora de uma função.

```
float Velocity = Random.Range(2.5f, 5.8f);
```

O próprio erro diz que você está atribuindo essa variável no iniciador de variáveis de instância.

Não atribua nenhuma variável fora do Start(que o Unity por padrão pede para você iniciar nela, que é o equivalente ao construtor), e seu código vai funcionar.

Solução: **Apenas crie uma variável fora das funções e inicialize ela dentro do Start.**

Lembre-se, **criar uma variável e iniciar uma variável são coisas diferentes.**

Comment: Ah, obrigado! Já corrigi! Então esse erro acontece porque não tem nunhum método pra chamar a função Random?

Comment: Esse erro acontece porque você está iniciando uma variável fora de um escopo de método e dentro do escopo da classe.

Você deve apenas iniciar uma variável dentro de métodos(funções).